# How to mock android Context in Mockk library

Tags: android, kotlin, mockk

I am trying to mock android Context but I keep getting an exception `no answer found for: Context(#3).getPackageName()`.
This is how I mock it:

```
val context = mockk<Context>()
```

and if I add relaxed to the mock, I get another exception, `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no tlvtree.library.path`